# Can all non-monotonic functions be treated as monotonic functions if we adequately partition it into sub-intervals?

Tags: calculus, functions

Monotonic functions defined in an interval must either increase or decrease(strictly or otherwise), whereas non-monotonic functions don't. But can we say that a non-monotonic function can be partitioned into many monotonic functions in various intervals?

Say, $y=x\sin x$, then for interval [0, 2.029] it is monotonic? Then again it seems for [2.029, 4.913] it is monotonic, or am I missing something?

Because then it would imply that all non-monotonic functions can be monotonic functions when defined at appropriate intervals.

I was reading "Calculus, Volume 1 - Tom Apostol" when I encountered monotonic
functions. Also any suggestions on learning calculus would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not necessarily, see the [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function) for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not exactly true. Someone gave the Dirichlet function as an example but you might think that that's super pathological so maybe this works for nicer functions. You can actually show that there exists a continuous function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ which is not monotone on any subinterval.

A standard proof of this is via the Baire Category Theorem, though there are also constructive proofs that you can read about. The Weierstrass function (which is continuous but nowhere differentiable) is an example of such a function.

On the other hand, the strategy of trying to consider the question for "nice enough" functions does lead somewhere.

Let $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is differentiable and is such that its derivative $f'$ is continuous. Let $a \in (0,1)$ be a point where $f'(a) > 0$. Since $f'$ is continuous, there is an open interval $I$ around $a$ in which $f' > 0$. So, $f$ is actually going to be monotone in this interval.

You can then go on and prove stronger results once you have more tools available to you, of course. This is just something for you to think about as you learn more about these things :)

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of pathological functions very much, you made me realize that any fractal curve would be a non-monotonic function! Also I am quite a novice in mathematics, so please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: You don't have to apologize for not knowing things, that's exactly why you're learning the subject :D

Comment: Thanks, I looked up The Weierstrass function, it seems to me that even though it is said to be a fractal curve in wikipedia, if I zoom enough it becomes smooth? Is it just the peculiarity of this function at low values of b?

Comment: This is where appearances can be deceiving. So, you have to realize that what you have is actually just a visual representation of the function and that has limited use in capturing what we want it to capture, especially given the limitations of technology and our own eyesight. The properties that we want are guaranteed by the explicit construction of the function.